# How to make a window with a glass background?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a window with a glass background, but it's not working. See my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            FillRect(GetDC(hWnd), &rect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
            return(0);
        } case WM_PAINT: {
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            rect.bottom = 262;
            FillRect(GetDC(hWnd), &rect, (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW);
            return(0);
        } case WM_CREATE: {
            if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater()) {
                BOOL IsCompositionEnabled = FALSE;
                DwmIsCompositionEnabled(&IsCompositionEnabled);
                if (IsCompositionEnabled) {
                    MARGINS margins = {0, 0, 0, 0};
                    margins.cyBottomHeight = 100;

                    HRESULT hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

                    }
                }
            }
            return(0);
        } case WM_CLOSE: {
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            return(0);
        } case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return(0);
        } default: {
            return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam));
        }
    }
}
```

This code makes the following window: [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J0tN.png)

This window is what I'm trying to do but there's a problem. When I move the window it blinks. Why does it blink?

Comment: Filling the background both in `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT` will definitely cause flickering. Return 0 from `WM_ERASEBKGND` and then just fill in the paint handler. Also every call to `GetDC` needs a matching call to `ReleaseDC` or you will soon run out of GDI resources. See the answer below for an example how to properly handle `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: Failure to call [BeginPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183362.aspx)/[EndPaint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162598.aspx) in your `WM_PAINT` handler will cause the invalid region to never get reset. As a consequence, your window will constantly update, once any part of it got invalidated.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things you should change:

When you handle `WM_PAINT`, you should call `BeginPaint` to get the DC and other info for your painting, then call `EndPaint` when you are done. This gives you a DC that restricts your painting to the clipping region needed, and prevents the flicker.

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    rect.bottom = 262;
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return(0);
}
```

You should also return 1 from `WM_ERASEBKGND` as you have done the erasing.

The `HDC` to use when erasing is passed in `wParam` so use that rather than the window DC.

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    FillRect((HDC)(wParam), &rect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: Calling `EndPaint` reduces the flickering, because it resets the invalid region, thus not requesting a repaint over and over again. The clipping is unrelated to flickering.